# Facebook Pixel - Submit Button

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, facebook

We just started our first Facebook campaign and are trying to track leads and conversions.  We created a pixel in FB and want to track when a user clicks `submit` on a contact form.  The issue is that our `submit` button doesn't take the user to a separate "confirmation" page, instead we just have a success message pop up on the contact form. The issue we're having is - that it's tracking both conversions and leads when you visit the website.  So we if someone goes to the website we see both a lead and conversion.  A lead should only appear when a user clicks "submit" on the form.

Below is the code we currently have:

```
// INITIALIZATION CODE
<script>
    ! function(f, b, e, v, n, t, s) {
        if (f.fbq) return;
        n = f.fbq = function() {
            n.callMethod ?
                n.callMethod.apply(n, arguments) : n.queue.push(arguments)
        };
        if (!f._fbq) f._fbq = n;
        n.push = n;
        n.loaded = !0;
        n.version = '2.0';
        n.queue = [];
        t = b.createElement(e);
        t.async = !0;
        t.src = v;
        s = b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(t, s)
    }(window,
        document, 'script', 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');

    fbq('init', '//OurIDGoesHere');
    fbq('track', "PageView");

    fbq('track', "Lead");
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
    src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=(OURIDCODE)&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
    /></noscript> // BUTTON CODE
<div class="button-wrap">
    <button id="talkButton" data-dialog="somedialog" class="triggercontact
    <i class=" fa fa-envelope "></i>Talk to Us!</button>
    </div>

    // CLICK EVENT CODE
    <script type="text/javascript ">
        $('#talkButton').click(function() {
          fbq('track', 'Lead', {
              content_category: 'Page'
          });
        });
    </script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the problem, is the standard event not firing?

Comment: Sorry the problem is that it's doubling.  So we if someone goes to the website we see both a lead and conversion.  A lead should only appear when a user clicks "submit" on the form.

Comment: That's because you're firing the lead event twice, once at the top of the page and once in the click handler.

Comment: So we should remove the first one, correct?

Comment: Yes, as per your description, only when users click the button, do they become a lead so the top one should not be there.  Also see the implementation guide for the list of events: https://www.facebook.com/business/help/952192354843755

Comment: Where in the documentation did you see the "Lead" standard event as taking a third argument please?

Comment: Here - https://www.facebook.com/business/help/www/1662592027337096

Comment: If you look at the standard events, you'll see that only Purchase takes a third argument.

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you!  Can you answer it so I can award you?

Comment: Sure, I think I should clarify my comment about the third parameter above, I meant only Purchase has required parameters, the extra parameters you can send with a standard event are listed here (I'll put all this info in an answer for you): https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/facebook-pixel/v2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For more information on implementing the standard events, I would recommend taking a look at this page where you get all the necessary details on standard and custom events (should you choose to use them):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-pixel/api-reference#events

The section on "Using Parameters with Events" is well worth a read.

The "Putting It All Together" section of that page is also really useful.

For your particular use case, take a look at the "Dynamic Events" section:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-pixel/api-reference#dynamicevents